# Determine size of page via HttpModule

Tags: asp.net

Here's an easy one for you:

I'm currently logging request duration via an HttpModule and I'd like to find out the number of bytes each page is as well.

`HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Length` throws a `NotSupportedException`.

What's an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an HttpModule that implements a stream rewriter.  It derives from the Stream class.  In my HttpModule I have the following code:

```
void app_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Filter = new MyRewriterStream(response.Filter);
}
```

In the stream class I have the following code that overrides the default Write method:

```
public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
{
     string outStr;
     outStr = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, offset, count);
     //Do useful stuff and write back to the stream
}
```

You can just take the length of the string at the second point

Comment: Do yo mean:

response.Filter = new MyRewriterStream(response.OutputStream)  ??

Comment: nevermind, you were right... it just looked like a typo.

That did it!

Comment: Be careful about converting the byte[] buffer to a string if the request is for a binary file.