# How can I track an asp.net pages size without tracing?

Tags: asp.net, size

I want to be able to track the amount of data that is being transfered from my web site to each user that accesses the site.  I can do this for file downloads and such but what about the pure html content itself.

How can I track the output size of a page (or the data that's trasnfered via an AJAX call) to the client and log it against a particular users session?

Also how would this differ when GZip is used in IIS 6.0?

Comment: Do you want to measure the bandwidth used or the text rendered? What about caching?

Answer (score 0):

You could develop a HttpModule to do this as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52311/determine-size-of-page-via-httpmodule). If you used a HttpModule to do this I would imagine compression is applied after this in IIS 6.0.

Answer (score 0):

One more way without writing any special code

You just get this parameter

```
Response.Filter.Length
```

Ref:
[Bandwidth Monitoring in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543038/bandwidth-monitoring-in-asp-net/2543458#2543458)

Comment: will that also capture the gzipped size or just the uncompressed size?

Comment: @Middletone I am not sure to answer because I do not have use it. You need to test it.